# SFINAE in variadic constructor

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, variadic-templates, c++17

I want to define a generic strong alias type, i.e. a type

```
template<typename T, auto ID = 0>
class StrongAlias {
    T value;
};
```

such that for a type `T` a `StrongAlias<T>` can be used in exactly the same way as `T`, but `StrongAlias<T, 0>` and `StrongAlias<T, 1>` are different types that can not be implecitly converted to each other.
In order to mimic a `T` as perfectly as possible, I would like my `StrongAlias` to have the same constructors as `T`.
This means I would like to do something like the following:

```
template<typename T, auto ID = 0>
class StrongAlias {
    T value;
public:
    // doesn't work
    template<typename... Args, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<T, Args...>>>
    StrongAlias(Args&&... args) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<T, Args...>)
        : value(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
};
```

except that this wouldn't work since the `template parameter pack must be the last template parameter`, as clang 5.0 would tell me.
The other way to use SFINAE that I thought of would be in the return type, but since a constructor doesn't have a return type, this does not seem to work either.

Is there any way to use SFINAE on a variadic template parameter pack in a constructor?

Alternatively, if there isn't one, can I accomplish what I want in another way?

Note that being implicitly constructible from a `T` isn't enough in my case, as the example of `StrongAlias<std::optional<int>>` shows: If `StrongAlias` can only be implictly constructed from a `std::optional<int>`, it cannot be be constructed from a `std::nullopt` (of type `std::nullopt_t`), because that would involve 2 user-defined conversions. I really want to have all constructors of the aliased type.

EDIT:
Of course it would be possible to implement this without SFINAE and let the program be invalid if a `StrongAlias` is constructed from incompatible arguments. However, while this would be an acceptable behaviour in my specific case, it is clearly not optimal as the `StrongAlias` may be used in a template that queries if the given type is constructible from some arguments (via `std::is_constructible`). While this would yield a `std::false_type` for `T`, it would result in a `std::true_type` for `StrongAlias<T>`, which could mean unnecessary compile errors for `StrongAlias<T>` that wouldn't exist for `T`.

Comment: Which clang 5.0 is telling you that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just change `std::enable_if_t` to a non-type template parameter:

```
template<typename T, auto ID = 0>
class StrongAlias {
    T value;
public:
    template<typename... Args, std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<T, Args...>, int> = 0>
    StrongAlias(Args&&... args) noexcept(noexcept(T(std::declval<Args>()...)))
        : value(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
};
```

Comment: I am wondering, whether you should write `Args...` or `Args&&...` in the packexpansion in `std::is_constructible_v<T, Args...>` ?

Comment: @Kilian Use `Args...` is enough. They are the same thing, because `std::declval` will add a `&&` automatically. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible

Comment: Thanks for your response!
An other question: What about explicit? while some constructors for T might be or might not be explicit, the consturctor for StrongAlias now is always non-explicit. The same applies for constexpr. But I think you can solve this just making the constructor constexpr.

Answer (score 4):

The two issues with your snippet that make it not compile are

- Trying to pass a type `std::is_constructible<T, Args...>` as the first argument of `std::enable_if_t`;
- Trying to pass `decltype(...)` to a `noexcept` operator.

(There's also a third problem with the function style cast inside the `noexcept`, but that only affects semantics, not compilability.)

Neither causes the error message you cite, which concerns a rule that doesn't apply to function templates at all. With these two problems fixed, Wandbox's Clang 5.0 happily accepts it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistakes in typing this here from memory, fixed it (I used `is_constructible_v` instead of `is_constructible` and no noexcept specifier in my original code)

Comment: @Irgendwhy Please provide a [mcve] that actually produces the error message you report. The fixed example compiles just fine on Wandbox.

Comment: you're right, but I swear I was getting that error message in my original code! Nevermind, it definitely works now and the entire premise of the question seems to be invalid. Should I delete it?