# Is the exception specification part of the immediate context in SFINAE?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, sfinae, noexcept

This is a follow-up to the following question: [SFINAE in variadic constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49372964/481267)

I wrote that some code such as

```
template<typename... Args>
StrongAlias(Args&&... args) noexcept(noexcept(T(std::declval<Args>()...)))
    : value(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
```

would disable the `StrongAlias` constructor in the case where `T` isn't constructible from the argument types, but another user told me that this wouldn't work because the exception specification isn't part of the immediate context.

Is the exception specification not part of the immediate context? I can't see why this would be the case.

Comment: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.deduct#7.note-1

Comment: @T.C. thanks, you should make that an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by T.C. in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49393142/is-the-exception-specification-part-of-the-immediate-context-in-sfinae#comment85788008_49393142), no.  Per [[temp.deduct]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.deduct#7.note-1):

> [ *Note:* The equivalent substitution in exception specifications is
>   done only when the *noexcept-specifier* is instantiated, at which
>   point a program is ill-formed if the substitution results in an
>   invalid type or expression.  — *end note* ]